# Javascript get plain text from server

Tags: javascript, html, get

I want to receive a plain text(or any document) from my server as a string variable and for example show it in alert I tried this solution

```
wordsurl = "http://alpha/test";
function ButtonClicked()    {
    showsentence(wordsurl)
}

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlhttp.send(); // NS_ERROR_FAILURE is here
}

function showsentence(generatorurl) {
    alert(httpGet(generatorurl));
}
```

but i'm getting NS_ERROR_FAILURE. Which is referring to the send.
Here is a [image: screenshot]

**How to get plain text from a server?**

Here is [Server code](https://bitbucket.org/Sheogorath2/web/src/ba0dc39afc3b518e83faa0050b9f0dcdda516414/srv/getsnt.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: what happens if you just enter this `http://alpha/test` in your browser?

Comment: http = hyper *text* transfer protocol, so it only speaks `strings = aka plain text`.. The question is, does your server work???

Comment: @webdev it gives me a plain string as you can see in screenshot with a simple header Content-type:text/plain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, now I see..

You should serve your html page from a `http://` server.. Not as a file `file://` 
So setup a simple http server, and try to access it again. You could also serve it from the same server, like your app logic

Comment: Ok.. now it gives me undefined in the alert box

Comment: @HermanYanush Why are you not using a framework, like jquery?

Comment: With jquery you only need to write: 
`$.get( "http://alpha/test", function( data ) {
  alert( data );
});`

Comment: It actually can receive a text if i put alert instead of return xmlhttp.responseText; it shows the text

Comment: @HermanYanush ok, cool, so the question is answered, the problem was, the missing server ;)

Comment: I tried jquery, but it says that ButtonClicked() is undefined

Comment: I'm noob in javascript and i am happy with essential things yet @webdeb

Comment: @HermanYanush no problem, you should open a new thread for the new question, regarding jquery ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. URL not found.(Is http://alpha/test in your computer?)

Maybe you can change file:// to http://

Comment: It doesn't matter if http://alpha/test is on the same machine or not, you see, that he can access it from his machine, so the connection works..