# How to use XMLHttpRequest in a command?

Tags: javascript

I have a discord bot, in which I am trying to add a command to get the top 10 players from a website, and to then have the bot say the top ten players as a message reply. I already have just a query on the site with a just a clean string in one page containing all the info I need: `1. Guangyuan \n2. Igutin \n3. calvinoclein` etc. All I want to do is just print that string directly into my bot, but all the examples for XMLHttpRequest are with html and there are browser checks and all that. This is my (very incomplete) code atm :

```
if (command === "top10") {
 function topplayers() {
 var top10;  
 };
msg.channel.sendMessage(top10);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [Javascript get plain text from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452181/javascript-get-plain-text-from-server)? What is that `msg.channel` - is it something that should be able to receive a reply?

Comment: msg.channel is just where the bot would send the reply. If I where to say !top10 than it should reply with the string top10. And that example you gave me is the same thing I keep seeing, there is different browser checks, and like open and sending in windows, and I dont get how that could work in a discord bot command.